# Check of Vertical/Horizontal returning aspect 1:1

Tags: javascript

i was doing another version of my project so i wanted to make avatar better,
im trying right now to make a function to check either the image is horizontal or vertical (or 1:1) but the code is returning that it is 1:1 when the image is vertical

```
function vhCheck(URL) {
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = URL;

            var result = onload = function() {
                var styleRes = 0;
                if (image.width > image.height) {
                    return (styleRes = "style='height: 100%; width: auto;'");
                } else if (image.width < image.height) {
                    return (styleRes = "style='height: auto; width:100%;'");
                } else if (image.width == image.height) {
                    return (styleRes = "style=' height: 100%; width: 100%;'");
                }
                return styleRes;
            };

            return result();

        }
```

Edit: i thought that might be helpful so i added my output from console

```
vhCheck("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0f/Eiffel_Tower_Vertical.JPG")
>"style=' height: 100%; width: 100%;'"
```

Comment: You should at least wait for the image to be loaded, which happens asynchronously.

Comment: forgot to add onload, but still doesn't work

Comment: `onload`? Where did you define that variable?

Comment: oh shoot, i forgot again to add `image.onload` but still, does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you call `result()` synchronously, while this should be called when the image has loaded. When it *does* get executed asynchronously, its return value is ignored. So `return styleRes` is going nowhere. When that executes, `vhCheck` has already long returned.

Either you have to set up a callback system, or do it with promises.

There is another little mistake: the height/width setting should be the inverse: when the width is the smallest you have a vertical image, and so the height should be 100% (at least if you want to see the whole image -- if you wanted to *clip* the image, it is fine as you have it).

I wouldn't worry too much about the third case where the image is square. Either of the two options will do then.

Finally, I'd use that style to set the `style` attribute of the image object, and resolve a promise with the image object that then has received that attribute:

```js
function vhCheck(URL) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = URL;
        image.onload = result;
        console.log("loading...", image.src);

        function result() {
            console.log("loaded!");
            var styleRes = image.width < image.height // or >
                ? 'height: 100%; width: auto;'
                : 'height: auto; width:100%;';
            image.setAttribute("style", styleRes);
            resolve(image);
        };
    });
}

vhCheck("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0f/Eiffel_Tower_Vertical.JPG")
    .then(function (image) {
        console.log(image);
        // do something more with image ...
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked for me :) and now i can get going with making that thing